# Distinguish between headset remote and Control Center music controls?

Tags: ios, uievent

Simple question really: is there a way to tell whether a user double-tapped their headset remote to skip a track, or whether they pushed the skip button in Control Center, for example?

I realise they both use the `RemoteControl` `UIEvent`, but I’m wondering if I can discern. I’d like to play a little auditory “beep” much like Spotify does upon skip or pause, but only when performed via a headset.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `- remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:` gives a `UIEvent` with a `type` and a `subtype` property.
The `type` property gives the same result when you press the button on the headset or on the lockscreen.

For me, there is no method to differenciate the events, except if you want to check if a headset is plugged to the device, but it is not perfect...